# When did Conan's glasses get zoom functionality added?

Tags: detective-conan

In epsisode 466,
Conan sees something down in a lake and Agasa says:

> Use the magnifying function of your glasses

Allowing Conan to zoom in and see the body floating.

[image: Screencap from episode 466 of Conan zooming in with his glasses]

I don't recall this functionality ever being mentioned before.  The way he mentions it and the way Conan responds makes it seem like it is obvious they both knew about it at this point. When did Professor Agasa add this feature to Conan's glasses?

Answer (score 3):

according to the detective conan wiki:4
Agasa updated the glasses so they can zoom in on a distant target and enhance visibility, even in the dark.
As of the anime episode The Unsmashable Snowman and Volume 54, Conan's glasses can only have some form of magnifying lens. This lens is on the right, according to the manga, while the Criminal Tracking Glasses feature is on the left lens. Movie 8 and Movie 11 are the only appearances that uses the left lens for the telescopic feature. Because movies are non-canon, it is unknown whether Conan's glasses have this modification on both lenses in conjunction with the criminal tracking feature, or if one modification would instead interfere with the other.

it was never stated when Agasa updated the lenses, and there is only a few appearances.
Hope this helps